# how to clean the data when the popup window is closed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function to close the popup window:

```
function unloadPopupBox() { // TO Unload the Popupbox
            $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style     
                "opacity": "1"  
            }); 
        }
```

I display this window in certain occasions that has chart in it. This chart has lots of data points and may slow down the browser. Is it possible to clean the data in this div when I close it. Instead of fadeOut, what other method can I use to get rid of the data in this popup_box div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `$('#popup_box').empty();` to empty the div. if you want to do it after fade animation is over then:

```
$('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow", function(){
  $(this).empty();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#popup_box').empty()
```

this clears the `div`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, one simple way is to delete the `innerHTML` of that `<div>`:

```
document.getElementByID(#ID).innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: yes, empty() is more efficient than innerHTML. Found this pretty cool test thats worth taking a look at if you have a lot of data, turns out a simple custom empty() function is WAY better than either jQuery empty() and innerHTML.